# Neo4j Cypher - Filtering nodes by Input nodes in common Doesn't resolve

Tags: neo4j, cypher, query-optimization

I have a large DB >1m customers, >100k products[image]

I am trying to build a product recommendation out of real-time data. However, the first query I build never resolves. (or at least I stop it after 30 min)

I want to INPUT a customer and Get All the Uses of the products they purchase. Then I want to get ALL Customers who have those same Uses AND More. (I was going to do things after that but can't get past this part)

ALL nodes are INDEXED on a unique ID.

```
MATCH (c:customer {customer_id:'0c4c518e5d1eaf3fc39f93463c2406ad8b659d6c22c9107179e3992f647b12aa'})-[:PURCHASE]->(p:product)-[:HAS]->(u:use)

WITH DISTINCT(u.section_id) as uses

MATCH (ac:customer)-[:PURCHASE]->(ap:product)-[:HAS]->(au:use)

WHERE au.section_id in uses

RETURN ac
```

Comment: Try this query:
MATCH (c:customer {customer_id:'0c4c518e5d1eaf3fc39f93463c2406ad8b659d6c22c9107179e3992f647b12aa'})-[:PURCHASE]->(p:product)-[:HAS]->(u:use)<-[:HAS]-(ap:product)<-[:PURCHASE]-(ac:customer) return ac

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, Marj. I tried your query and the Neo4j Desktop crashed :(
I have increased heap and other sizes to make sure I'm allocating enough memory.

Comment: I have been able to get to where I want to go by advancing One relation at a time however, this is taking a long time   (Started streaming 1 records after 1 ms and completed after 236449 ms.)


MATCH (c:customer
 {customer_id:'0c4c518e5d1eaf3fc39f93463c2406ad8b659d6c22c9107179e3992f647b12aa'})-[:PURCHASE]->(p:product)-[:HAS]->(u:use)
WITH COLLECT(DISTINCT u.section_id) as uses, COLLECT(DISTINCT p.product_code) as products
MATCH (ac:customer)-[:PURCHASE]->(ap:product)
WHERE ap.product_code in products
RETURN DISTINCT (ac)

Comment: So, by increasing the available memory, your original query is now completing in about 4 minutes?
How many customers are you getting returned?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I build a NEW Query that does the full Recommendation. But still takes 1min...
I believe the issue was I was Matching Up to :use and then going back this must have been getting just way too many nodes to sort through.

```
MATCH (c:customer {customer_id:'0c4c518e5d1eaf3fc39f93463c2406ad8b659d6c22c9107179e3992f647b12aa'})-[:PURCHASE]->(p)<-[:PURCHASE]-(oc)
MATCH (u:use)<-[:HAS]-(p)-[:HAS]->(h:color)-[:IS_A]->(ph)     
WHERE c <> oc  AND oc.age > (c.age-10) AND oc.age < (c.age+10) 
MATCH (oc)-[:PURCHASE]->(np)-[:HAS]->(u)  
WITH p, np, ph, u, COLLECT(DISTINCT p.gra_id) as styles 
WHERE p.product_code <> np.product_code AND np.gra_id in styles AND (np)-[:HAS]->(:color)-[:IS_A]->(ph) 
WITH u.name as use, np.article_id as product, count(*) as score 
ORDER BY score DESC 
RETURN use, collect(product)[0..6] as products 
ORDER BY use
```